# File upload using Akka HTTP

Tags: scala, file-upload, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I am trying to implement file upload functionality in my application using Akka HTTP. I am using `akka-stream` version `2.4.4`.

Here is the code (modified from [akka-doc](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.6/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/file-upload-directives/fileUpload.html))

```
path("fileupload") {
    post {
      extractRequestContext {
        ctx => {
          implicit val materializer = ctx.materializer
          implicit val ec = ctx.executionContext
          fileUpload("fileUpload") {
            case (metadata, byteSource) =>
              val location = FileUtil.getUploadPath(metadata)
              val updatedFileName = metadata.fileName.replaceAll(" ", "").replaceAll("\"", "")
              val uniqFileName = uniqueFileId.concat(updatedFileName)
              val fullPath = location + File.separator + uniqFileName
              val writer = new FileOutputStream(fullPath)
              val bufferedWriter = new BufferedOutputStream(writer)

              val result = byteSource.map(s => {
                bufferedWriter.write(s.toArray)
              }).runWith(Sink.ignore)

              val result1 = byteSource.runWith(Sink.foreach(s=>bufferedWriter.write(s.toArray)))
              Await.result(result1, 5.seconds)
              bufferedWriter.flush()
              bufferedWriter.close()
              complete(uniqFileName)
            /*onSuccess(result) { x =>
              bufferedWriter.flush()
              bufferedWriter.close()
              complete("hello world")
            }*/
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This code is working fine and is uploading the file to the given path. I am generating new file names by appending UUID to make sure that the file names are unique. So I need to return the new file name to the caller. However, this method is not returning the filename always. Sometimes, it is finishing with `Response has no content`.

Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but look into http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.6/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#file-io-sinks-and-sources instead of manually writing to a file. Also, using Await.result inside a route is really bad style.

Comment: Will look at that. I tried with onSuccess instead of Await, bust same. So I tried with Await. Thanks for the reply, let me try the link.

Comment: @RüdigerKlaehn I tried with FileIO, still the same issue exist :(

Comment: I think the real reason for "Response has no content" is that you are reading 'byteSource' twice, for 'result' and 'result1'. If 'result' got there first, there's nothing for 'result1' to consume.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no need to use the standard blocking streams when you have reactive streams for that purpose:

```
  path("fileUpload") {
    post {
      fileUpload("fileUpload") {
        case (fileInfo, fileStream) =>
          val sink = FileIO.toPath(Paths.get("/tmp") resolve fileInfo.fileName)
          val writeResult = fileStream.runWith(sink)
          onSuccess(writeResult) { result =>
            result.status match {
              case Success(_) => complete(s"Successfully written ${result.count} bytes")
              case Failure(e) => throw e
            }
          }
      }
    }
  }
```

This code will upload `fileUpload` multipart field to a file inside `/tmp` directory. It just dumps the content of the input source to the respective file sink, returning a message upon the completion of the write operation.

You may also want to tweak the dispatcher used for `FileIO` sources and sinks, as described in [their scaladocs](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.6/index.html#akka.stream.scaladsl.FileIO$).

Comment: Even with this, I am not getting the response sometimes :( . It shows 'The response was empty'.  Only difference is that I am using 2.4.4 instead of 2.4.6.

Comment: How do you test it? Curl? Is it a very large file?

Comment: I am testing using the Chome Extension, Advanced Rest client. The file is not very large. Tried with txt, sql, jpeg, png files. min 3kb to max 2 mb.

Comment: Replace your code with the one suggested by @VladimirMatveev and see if you can reproduce the issue with curl. Add the steps to reproduce to the question. Then you have a decent chance of somebody helping you.

Comment: This answer worked great for me. I just had to add the following to my `application.conf` to avoid an `EntityStreamSizeException`: `parsing.max-content-length = infinite`

Answer (score 2):

If you need only uploading a file but not doing anything until upload finishes in the file stream, then there is much simpler way:

```
def tempDestination(fileInfo: FileInfo): File =
  File.createTempFile(fileInfo.fileName, ".tmp")

val route =
  storeUploadedFile("csv", tempDestination) {
    case (metadata, file) =>
      // do something with the file and file metadata ...
      file.delete()
      complete(StatusCodes.OK)
  }
```

See docs: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/file-upload-directives/storeUploadedFile.html

Comment: are you using NIO?

Comment: No in this case. For NIO it should be `Files` instead of `File`